# Nome da coluna Dinâmica Linq?

Tags: c#, linq, expressões-lambda

Tenho uma coluna que receberá o `orderBy` dinamicamente, por *exemplo*:

```
_context.Tabela
   .Where(p => 
        p.colunaA.Contains(searchBy) ||
        p.colunaB.Contains(searchBy) ||
        p.colunaC.Contains(searchBy) ||
        p.colunaD.Contains(searchBy)
   )
   .OrderByDescending(p => p.colunaA)
```

como colocar esta coluna `p => p.colunaA` dinamica? Podendo ser colunas A, B,C ou D. Testei várias formas e não consegui chegar a um `SelectedColumn`.

Comment: São quantas colunas? como você defini qual coluna é para ser ordenada? tem como explicar melhor?

Answer (score 0):

Tem um package chamado System.Linq.Dynamic que tem uma opção de passar o nome da coluna como string, isso deve resolver seu problema:

```
var coluna = "colunaDinamica";
....
.OrderByDescending(coluna);
```

Inclusive pode informar a ordem, por exemplo "nomeDaColuna DESC"

Eu uso em .Net Core, o package é esse: https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Linq.Dynamic.Core

Comment: Fiz da maneira que respondi, mas testei desta forma que respondeu e funcionou perfeitamente, obrigado!

Answer (score -1):

Acabei encontrando uma maneira simples:

```
var propertyInfo = typeof(Resultados).GetProperty("nomeDaColuna");
_context.Tabela.AsEnumerable().OrderByDescending(x => propertyInfo.GetValue(x, null))
```

Net core 3+ como estava retornando uma lista precisei do AsEnumerable(), anterior não testei pra confirmar a necessidade

Comment: o jeito que você fez está errado, porque causa uma mau desempenho, tudo isso tem que ser feito antes de materializar o resultado, Do jeito que você fez carrega todo a carga e depois ordena, é melhor já vir ordenado, ou seja, está usando errado.